# Finding the rate of change for the viewing angle

Tags: calculus

The bottom of a large theator screen is 3 ft above your eye level and the top of the screen is 10 ft above your eye level.  Assume you walk away from the screen (perpendicular to the screen) at a rate of 3 ft/s while looking at the screen.  What is the rate of change of the viewing angle $\theta$ when you are 30 ft from the wall on which the screen hangs, if the floor is horizontal?

This is my attempt, but it's wrong... Why?

Let the angle $\alpha$ be between the floor and your eye level.

[image]

$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{3}{x} \implies \frac{d \alpha}{dx}=\frac{-3}{9+x^2}$$
$$\tan(\alpha + \theta) = \frac{13}{x} \implies \frac{d \theta}{dx} + \frac{d \alpha}{dx} = \frac{-13}{169+x^2}$$
$$\frac{d \theta}{dx} = \frac{-13}{169+x^2} + \frac{3}{9+x^2}$$

But when I plug in $x=30$, I get $\frac{d \theta}{dx} = -0.00886$ when the answer is $\frac{d \theta}{dx}=-0.0201$

Where did I go wrong? I can't figure it out.  I've even checked my derivatives using online calculators and everything is right... so something must be wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues with your work.

(1)  The $10$ in your diagram should be a $7$ (so that the total height is $10$).

(2) Second, their answer is using a time derivative (with respect to $t$), not an $x$ derivative.  So you'll have to take into account that $\frac{dx}{dt}=3$ ft/sec.

Comment: Oh, I guess I read the question wrong.  Also, how do I know what I am supposed to take the derivative in respect to? The question was sort of vague, am I to assume that I should have used time because they provided dx/dt = 3ft/s

Comment: Usually in related rates problems the rate of change is with respect to time.  Although I can see that it could be ambiguous depending on the wording of the problem.